# Foreground service that stops running

Tags: android, android-service

I'm having a problem with an app I'm writing. The app should record the network's data - lac, cell Id and receiving power into a file, whenever one of it changes. To continue recording while the app is not in focus or while the device sleeps, I used foregound service. As soon as the screen goes off, my service stops recording. The recording resumes when the screen is on.

Here's my code:
For calling the service -

```
i = new Intent(this, WriteToFileService.class);
startService(i);
```

The code from the service -

```
private PhoneStateListener MyServiceListener;
private TelephonyManager tm;
private int lac ,cellId, signal;
private String phoneState;
private File outFile;
private final static int myID = 10;
//PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent senderIntent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    localIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, localIntent, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker("Starting to record data").setContentTitle("NetInfo").setContentText("Recording data").setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true).setContentIntent(pendIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.hexagon);   //.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;       
    startForeground(myID, notification);
    //PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    //wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    //wl.acquire();

    outFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), senderIntent.getStringExtra("name"));
    tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    MyServiceListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location){
            super.onCellLocationChanged(location);
            if ((tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA) || (tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS)) {
                GsmCellLocation MyLocation = (GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();
                lac = MyLocation.getLac();
                cellId = MyLocation.getCid();
            }
            if (tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA) {
                CdmaCellLocation MyLocation = (CdmaCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();
                lac = 0;
                cellId = MyLocation.getBaseStationId();
            }
            WriteDataToFile(lac, cellId, signal, phoneState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
            signal = 2 * signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() - 113;   
            WriteDataToFile(lac, cellId, signal, phoneState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                phoneState = "Idle";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                phoneState = "Ringing";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                phoneState = "On-going call";
                break;
            default:
                phoneState = "";
                break;
            }
            WriteDataToFile(lac, cellId, signal, phoneState);
        }
    };
    tm.listen(MyServiceListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

private void WriteDataToFile(int lac, int cellId, int signal, String phoneState)
{

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outFile.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);         
        bw.append(new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + " ");
        bw.append(String.valueOf(lac) + " ");
        bw.append(String.valueOf(cellId) + " ");
        bw.append(String.valueOf(signal) + " ");
        bw.append(phoneState + "\n");           
        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stopped recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    tm.listen(MyServiceListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    //wl.release();
    stopForeground(true);
```

And of-course that `OnDestroy()` ends with `stopForeground(true);`
I've added at some stage a message to the file when the service is being destroyed, but it occured only once - when I ended the service, so I'm sure that it was not killed by the OS.
Is there any way to implement this with foreground service, or should I try a different approach?

I've tried it on two different devices - LG P500 with android 2.2 and samsung S3 mini with android 4.1. Both of them had the same behaviour.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to get a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOC from the [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)

> Wake lock level: Ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard backlight will be allowed to go off.
>
> If the user presses the power button, then the screen will be turned off but the CPU will be kept on until all partial wake locks have been released.

PseudoCode in your onStartCommand…

```
startForeground(myID, notification);
...

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOC, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
return Service.START_STICKY;
```

In your service onDestroy (or when you are done with the Foreground) do a:

```
 wl.release();
```

What's probably happening is that the device's CPU is also going to sleep ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I just thought that since the device still listens to network events even when it sleeps, my service will keep getting the updates.

Comment: No, it still stops recording when the device sleeps, and resumes when the device wakes. I've tested it only on my LG. Tomorrow I'll test it on the S3 mini, but I'm a little skeptic.

Comment: Well, in that case you might want to show us when/what/who are you doing, because I think the problem is not in your service per se.

Comment: I've added the full code of the service. What else do you want to know?

Comment: same problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52987783/6605907) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53090171/6605907) which `WakeLock` doesn't work

Comment: I don't know what can the cause be @Mehran the app i'm currently working on runs a Foreground Service (even when the app is in the background) and we do not observe these issues (yet?). Have you read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power and https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby to make sure you're doing "all you can" ?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini this issue appears in some devices not all of them. for example in `LineageOS` `samsung j5 api24`   works fine. but not in `honor 8 lite api24` . thanks for sharing the links I'll look into it.

Comment: @Mehran keep in mind that the documentation states that certain things are _prone to the specific vendor implementation_ (in other words, each vendor may modify some behaviors…). That's a bad idea (i blame google for that one), but keep that in mind. Not all devices are created equal :/