# Foreground service stops while running a long task

Tags: android, foreground-service

I have a foreground service that should execute a long-running (~20 minutes) task in a single go (a file transfer using Bluetooth). However, the service gets stopped after a while.

As a simple test app that reproduces the issue, I did the following, first the activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            TestService serv = ((TestService.TestServiceBinder) service).getService();
            serv.startLongProcess();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, i);
        bindService(i, connection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

And then the service:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "TestService";

    public static class TestServiceBinder extends Binder {
        private final TestService service;

        public TestServiceBinder(TestService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        public TestService getService() {
            return service;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new TestServiceBinder(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            nm.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel("channel", "channel", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW));
        }

        startForeground(42, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel")
                .setContentTitle("Title")
                .setContentText("Content")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build());
    }

    public void startLongProcess() {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "com.example.longrunningproject");
        wakeLock.acquire(1000 * 60 * 30);
        new Thread(() -> {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Doing work: " + i);
                i++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Now, I launch the app, but it on background (the notification persists) and turn the screen off. As I observe the logcat output, I see the following:

```
2018-10-25 13:58:26.982 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 964
2018-10-25 13:58:28.027 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 965
2018-10-25 13:58:29.068 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 966
2018-10-25 13:58:29.552 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 2 when =3493022 package =android operation = null listenTag =*job.delay* flags =0x0
2018-10-25 13:58:30.114 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 967
2018-10-25 13:58:31.157 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 968
2018-10-25 13:58:32.198 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 969
2018-10-25 13:58:33.242 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 970
2018-10-25 13:58:34.287 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 971
2018-10-25 13:58:34.655 886-11349/? E/OHPD: [BgDetect] AppForkedProc kworker/2:0H pid 11129 uid 0 can't find pkgName
2018-10-25 13:58:35.330 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 972
2018-10-25 13:58:36.374 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 973
2018-10-25 13:58:37.419 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 974
2018-10-25 13:58:37.869 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@5d7ffa9[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6]
2018-10-25 13:58:37.871 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: LightweightExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@293892e[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 44]
2018-10-25 13:58:37.872 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: bgExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@4319ccf[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 8]
2018-10-25 13:58:38.464 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 975
2018-10-25 13:58:39.490 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 976
2018-10-25 13:58:39.983 11212-11232/? W/CrashLoopRemedyLog: unable to delete remedy log, instaCrash: true
2018-10-25 13:58:40.535 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 977
2018-10-25 13:58:41.580 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 978
2018-10-25 13:58:42.625 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 979
2018-10-25 13:58:43.669 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 980
2018-10-25 13:58:44.714 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 981
2018-10-25 13:58:45.735 10768-10794/com.example.expell.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 982
2018-10-25 13:58:46.752 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 983
2018-10-25 13:58:47.773 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 984
2018-10-25 13:58:48.794 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 985
2018-10-25 13:58:48.938 911-1030/? I/ThermalEngine: Monitor : quiet_therm = 28899, msm_therm = 29311, xo_therm = 29403, battery_therm = 283,current_now = -442000 
2018-10-25 13:58:49.804 10768-10794/com.example.longrunningproject D/TestService: Doing work: 986
2018-10-25 13:58:52.887 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 3 when =3516357 package =com.google.android.gms operation =*alarm*:com.google.android.gms/.lockbox.LockboxAlarmReceiver flags =0x0
2018-10-25 13:59:00.004 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 3 when =3523475 package =android operation =*alarm*:android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flags =0x1
2018-10-25 13:59:35.512 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 2 when =3558982 package =com.google.android.gms operation =*walarm*:com.google.android.gms.gcm.HEARTBEAT_ALARM flags =0x5
2018-10-25 13:59:35.545 748-970/? D/AudioPolicyService: setRecordSilenced() uid 99910027 on silenced 0
2018-10-25 13:59:35.551 2408-8056/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2018-10-25 13:59:35.867 709-2516/? I/WifiHAL: event received NL80211_CMD_VENDOR, vendor_id = 0x1374, subcmd = 0xa
2018-10-25 13:59:35.870 2496-2496/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-AVOID-FREQ ranges=5180-5320,5500-5640
2018-10-25 13:59:35.871 2496-2496/? I/wpa_supplicant: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-AVOID-FREQ ignore
2018-10-25 13:59:37.902 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: BlockingExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@5d7ffa9[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 6]
2018-10-25 13:59:37.903 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: LightweightExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@293892e[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 44]
2018-10-25 13:59:37.904 4682-4697/? I/Finsky: [50] com.google.android.finsky.bo.ad.run(6): Stats for Executor: bgExecutor com.google.android.finsky.bo.ae@4319ccf[Running, pool size = 4, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 8]
2018-10-25 13:59:40.722 886-893/? W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2018-10-25 13:59:48.953 911-1030/? I/ThermalEngine: Monitor : quiet_therm = 28899, msm_therm = 29266, xo_therm = 29403, battery_therm = 284,current_now = -443000 
2018-10-25 13:59:52.732 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 1 when =1540465192731 package =android operation =*alarm*:com.oneplus.android.screenOffCheckProcessState flags =0x9
2018-10-25 14:00:00.000 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 3 when =3583475 package =android operation =*alarm*:android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flags =0x1
2018-10-25 14:00:01.004 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 1 when =1540465201000 package =com.oneplus.deskclock operation =*alarm*:com.android.deskclock.ON_QUARTER_HOUR flags =0x1
2018-10-25 14:00:27.192 886-1358/? V/AlarmManager: Triggering alarm #0: 3 when =3610662 package =android operation =*alarm*:android/com.android.server.stats.StatsCompanionService$PullingAlarmReceiver flags =0x9
2018-10-25 14:00:27.922 692-754/? E/CHRE: Couldn't connect client socket to 'chre': Connection refused
2018-10-25 14:00:27.925 692-754/? W/CHRE: Failed to (re)connect, next try in 300000 ms
```

So, basically after 16 minutes of running, everything halts. On another run, it halted after 5 minutes. When the screen is turned back on (even without bringing the activity to foreground), the service will continue execution. How do I get the service to function correctly for the full duration of the operation?

Comment: see `android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock` documentation

Comment: @pskink Tried with acquiring a wakelock, the issue persists.

Comment: post your code with `Wakelock` then

Comment: @pskink Added the wakelock code already.

Comment: hmmm, tried to call `newWakeLock` and `acquire` inside the new `Thread`? the docs dont say anything about the threads but...

Comment: @pskink Tried that, but it still halts. Similarly, I tried to run the service in a different process, but that didn't help either.

Comment: is it really a `foreground service`? do you see its icon in notification bar?

Comment: Possibly because `wakeLock` is a local variable that immediately goes out of scope?

Comment: @pskink Yes, the notification is visible at all times.

Comment: @greeble31 I tried storing the wakelock in a field, but it did nothing.

Comment: By the way what version of Android are you running, and what API level for your app?

Comment: @greeble31 compileSdk and targetSdk 28, running on Pie 9.0. I suspect this is an issue in how Oneplus 6 handles foreground services; there was another thread with decompiled Oneplus sources which showed some evidence.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to get my hardware devices to sleep while the USB cable is attached, and the emulator won't sleep either. Cannot reproduce the issue. FWIW, locally declared `WakeLocks` are finalized synchronously in the function epilogue, and according to the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.0.1_r1/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java), that causes them to release(). So, it's not reasonable to expect this to work with your code (as posted), you _must_ hang on to a reference.

Comment: @greeble31 I changed the wakelock so that the reference is stored in a field and the wakelock is acquired during `onCreate()`- the issue persists.

Comment: @greeble31 I'm running ADB over wi-fi which gets around the charging issue. Another way is to invoke `adb shell dumpsys battery unplug`, but I don't rely on that since it messes up other things as well (ie. other apps start dying in the background too).

Comment: Hmm, I tried that on my S6, unfortunately it still would not sleep, even after an hour! I guess that explains why my battery is always dying... Good luck.

Comment: I have the same issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53090171/6605907) ... Any solutions!?

Comment: Have you considered using the (new) Work Manager to schedule this work? That's what it was created for.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Rewrote the log-printing logic as a worker. About nine minutes of running, I got an error `Work [ ... ] failed because it threw an exception/error: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.` It seems that whatever underlying system it was using to execute the work got cancelled by the system.

Comment: Interesting finding; seems like the hardware is either unhappy with the long running job or something is amiss. It's impossible to tell without access to your entire code and your device, but I'd consider the chance that more devices may behave like this (especially on the lower end of the spectrum) and code defensively against it. :-/

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I just tried `WorkManager`. created a countdown and logged the value inside `doWork`. It paused counting down while phone was not attached to charge and screen was off. and of course after unlocking phone the job resumed. tried with `setRequiresDeviceIdle(true/false)`. the same.

Comment: @Mehran Well perhaps that warrants its own question; someone with more Work Manager experience (including some Google devs who roam here @ Stack Overflow from time to time) may chime in and help ;) I suggest you try a simple example (instead of your full code). Create a simple app that runs a background job and see if that device still does the same or if this is something that maybe your specific app is experiencing. It's the best way to isolate the issue and above all, to be able to easily demonstrate it in case google needs "proof" in a Bug report. (they usually ask for sample prjs)

Comment: (try not to use Bluetooth in your sample; I have the impression maybe the Bluetooth stack is the culprit).

Comment: thanks  @MartinMarconcini , I will do that.

Comment: @manabreak Maybe deep doze is the problem: [blog post](https://developer.zebra.com/community/home/blog/2017/05/04/keeping-your-application-running-when-the-device-wants-to-sleep)