# Service gets paused while app is in background && screen is locked

Tags: android, android-service

Inside a Foreground Service I encode media with [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org). By logging the encode progress I noticed the process gets paused(in some devices)

while `device connected to adb over wifi(NOT USB) && screen is locked`.

I tried :

```
    try {
        final PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (mgr != null) {
            wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "TAG:WakeLock");
            if (!wakeLock.isHeld()) {
                wakeLock.acquire();
                Log.i("AppController","Engaging WakeLock");
            }else{
                Log.i("AppController","WakeLock was already engaged");

            }

        }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```

Tried `AlarmManager` inside `Application` class  ||  `My service` class.

I tried [commonsguy/cwac-wakeful](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Tried `ignore battery optimization`

Still CPU goes to sleep after one minute process.

**Service**

```
public class CompressionService extends Service {

private Messenger _activityMessenger;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    _activityMessenger = intent.getParcelableExtra(MESSENGER_INTENT_KEY);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

private final IFFmpegProcessService.Stub mBinder = new IFFmpegProcessService.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void startEncode(final List<String> ffmpegArgs, final String outputFile)  {
        ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler handler = new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(String s) {
                long progress = FFmpegUtil.getProgres(s);
                Log.d("JOB_PROGRESS: " + progress);
                sendMessage(progress);

            }
        };
        FFmpegUtil.call(handler);
    }
    @Override public void cancel() throws RemoteException { }
    @Override public boolean isEncoding() throws RemoteException {return false; }
};



private void sendMessage(@Nullable Object params) {
    Message m = Message.obtain();
    m.what = MessageId.JOB_PROGRESS.ordinal();
    m.obj = params;
    try {
        _activityMessenger.send(m);
    } catch (RemoteException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
}


}
```

Running on `API 24 || API 26` `Honor 8 Lite`

Comment: all Indication in the code that the server is not "real" background ... first why Service and not IntentService.. second you are using START_NOT_STICKY which says it can be paused.. plus Android is closing/pausing services to allocate cpu for other proccess .. you need to consider that too.

Comment: @ItzikSamara I tried `START_STICKY` still the same. I'll try `IntentService`,  "plus Android is closing/pausing services to allocate cpu for other proccess", Yes, but not when user wants to perform a long task over night.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement it as `ForegroundService`. It is required to avoid the pausing at least from API Level 26.

Comment: it is a `ForegroundService`.

Comment: @Mehran no, it is not. You need to create a notification and call `startForeground`, check the docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#java

Comment: sorry, I removed my notification code to be easier for reading.

Comment: Try WorkManager instead? It replaces AlarmManager and JobScheduler.